# How to set height of inner div (img) in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, jquery, css

How can I set minimum div height inside of bootstrap carousel while keeping entire image scaled to div height. In other words I've got image 1920x1080 and everything looks great above `~992px` (image no.1). But while shrinking website to mobile view (below `992px`) image inside carousel is scaling also, what is kind of recommended (image no.2) . But I want to have a declared div height (mainly `img` size) that is fully scaled to that height (width of image has to be untouched, image can't not be cropped). Image no.3 shows the effect which I want to achieve.

Views  - recommended to watch for better understanding:-

[image]

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.carousel-caption h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.carousel-caption h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
    <div id="slides" class="carousel slide background-carousele" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="container-fluid carousel-main">
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <!-- <img src="http://rosewood.ancorathemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/slide1.jpg" alt="Background Image 1"> -->
                <img src="images/C8.jpg" alt="Background Image 1">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1 class="display-2">Witamy w </h1>
                    <h1 class="display-2">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item ">
                <img src="images/C3.jpg" alt="Background Image 2">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1 class="display-2">Lorem ipsum 2 </h1>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item ">
                <img src="/images/C7.jpg" alt="Background Image 3">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1 class="display-2">Lorem ipsum 3 </h1>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I tried to use mediaqueries to set up div height but it doesn't work as I want.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .carousel-item {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to reduce the distortion very well to work for your preference of using a min-height. Let brainstorm 1920x800 if keeping aspect ratio => 768x320. If we use 768x320 for @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) and smaller. And if we keep min-height:300px. It will be 1920/768=2.5, i.e at least 2.5 less distortion than using the original 1920x

Please make 2 extra copies 992x413 and 768x320 and use below code to edit into your file. Let me know how it works out.

```
<div class="carousel_img">
    <img src="link-to-768.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</div>

<style>
/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .carousel_img {
      background: url('link-to-1920.jpg') no-repeat;
      height: 800px;
    }
  }
  
  /********** Medium devices only **********/
  @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #carousel_img {
        background: url('link-to-992.jpg') no-repeat;
        height: 413px;
      }    
  }
  
  /********** Small devices only **********/
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    #carousel_img {
        background: url('link-to-768.jpg') no-repeat;
        height: 413px;
      } 
  }
  
  /********** Extra small devices only **********/
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    
  }
  
  
  /********** Super extra small devices Only (e.g., iPhone 4) **********/
  @media (max-width: 479px) {
    
    .col-xxs-12 {   /*This col-xxs is not defined in Bootstrap but very useful. I put here in case you need*/
      position: relative;
      min-height: 1px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  </style>
```